# What does it look when we travel at the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, universe, speed, space-travel

Suppose we're in a spaceship or in a car which runs at the speed of light.

We are watching the light which is coming towards eyes at the speed of the light.
**What would it look like when the driver see through the window**?

Comment: According to Einstein's special theory of relativity, it's impossible to travel *at* the speed of light. (At least for any massive object, like cars and spaceships and people)

Comment: Read this introduction to [Special Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_special_relativity) .

Comment: IIRC Feynman constructed a result about collisions between quarks and photons by modelling the quarks as flat disks, justifying this as, from the photon's point of view, everything becomes perfectly thin and flat in the forward direction.